# Android and JSON. Catching an exception - wrong link

Tags: android, json, exception

I'm making an app which will communicate with the server throught JSON. User can input address of the server and I want to provide controlled bahaviour when user will input wrong link. I do not want to hide problem by catching general exception, I want to catch specific one, but I can't figure it how.

This is a log, when user will input wrong link:

```
01-19 00:08:10.205: W/dalvikvm(12576): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410af2a0)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error     occured while executing doInBackground()
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=aaaaaasss
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.jav    a:591)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at         org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     pl.mosek.micro.JSONParser.makeHttpRequestJSONObject(JSONParser.java:62)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     pl.mosek.micro.SignInActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(SignInActivity.java:287)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     pl.mosek.micro.SignInActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(SignInActivity.java:1)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-19 00:08:10.220: E/AndroidRuntime(12576):    ... 5 more
```

This is JSONParser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static JSONArray jArray = null;
static String json = "";
private boolean started = false;
private boolean finished = false;

public static String getJson() {
    return json;
}

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequestJSONObject(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    finished = false;
    started = true;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    started = false;
    finished = true;
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public JSONArray makeHttpRequestJSONArray(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    finished = false;
    started = true;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    started = false;
    finished = true;
    // return JSON String
    return jArray;

}

public boolean isStarted() {
    return started;
}

public boolean isFinished() {
    return finished;
}

}
```

What should I do to catch specific exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch :

```
IllegalStateException (Exception e)
```

Or you can check for the input for errors before executing the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
pl.mosek.micro.JSONParser.makeHttpRequestJSONObject(JSONParser.java:62)
```

I don't know where is your line (62), but you can see the error:

> Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null,
>   host=null, path=aaaaaasss

I think you should check null before use.

In this line:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

Is params null?

And almost important, Please check your InputStream

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

Is `is` null?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings in a way Java can't.

It should be:

```
if ("POST".equals(method))
```

None of you're IFs evaluate to true so you aren't setting a URL and the HTTP object is choking.